# Scifi short story with alien standing guard against vicious aliens (that turn out to be humans)

Tags: story-identification

A long time ago I read a short story about a soldier posting guard on a far away planet and remembering when the war started, the way that the aliens didn't try to talk with them and they just attacked them. The soldier sees an alien and kills it and the way it describes the alien makes you understand that ***man was the alien all along.***

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HumanAllAlong

Comment: Wow. What an amazing twist.

Comment: There are quite a few questions on here where humans are the Big Bad unknown alien.

Comment: Fredrick Brown's _"Sentry"_? If so, there is surely an answered question this can be marked a duplicate of.

Comment: http://www.lupinworks.com/glit6756/informant/sai3/sentry.pdf - As a buttress to ^^

Comment: @lfurini - Then it was done wrong. If OP ever confirms the answer here, mark it as dup of the one with the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey yeah, it was Sentry, I'm new so do I have to mark it as a dub or can an admin do it? Thanks for the help